# How to get email address from vk.api?

Tags: javascript, vk

Im trying to get email address. After success login i have firstname, lastname, all except email. please help.

```
VK.Auth.login(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {


            } else {

            }
        }, 4194304);
```

Comment: email is only for websites (mask +4194304). https://vk.com/dev/permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Vk is specific social network.

Answer (score 7):

When you get Access Token, VK also gives you Email and User ID, but you need specific permission for that - "email".

Comment: That's the correct answer! Just have made id that way. I would be glad if I could first read this, then look all over other places in the internet. :)

Answer (score 1):

vk.com now has that functionality. Try checking out this documentation page: https://vk.com/dev/permissions

Comment: The author above (Evgeniy Shinkarenko) has described the probem from pointed you documentation, He asked why is it not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this way does not give the email. But there is the way to get email via OAuth (for sites vk.com/dev/auth_sites), email will be returned in GET parameters along with token.

in Coffescript/Javascript you can use window.open(...)

```
appId = 'your app id'
redirectUri = 'your redirect uri'
url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id='+appId+'&display=popup&redirect_uri='+redirectUri+'&response_type=token&scope=email'

newWin = window.open(url, 'vk-login', 'width=665,height=370')
```

And later you have two way to get email

1. On redirect uri handler (server way)
2. do redirect to any place of your site and every second check newWin.location.href a when it will be if (newHref.indexOf(redirectUri) != -1) then extract the parameter email (client way)

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.open

```
var url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://yoursite.com&response_type=token'

        var newWin = window.open(url, 'vk-login', 'width=665,height=370')
        newWin.onload = function() {
          var hash = newWin.location.hash
          console.log(hash)
        }
```